# DNS for redirect domain with https form aaa.com to bbb.com

Tags: redirect, dns

We had old site https://www.aaa.com hosted on Azure and DNS for aaa.com on GoDaddy.
Now we made new site https://www.bbb.com hosted on AWS and DNS for bbb.com on Azure.
I need all users clicking on https://www.aaa.com link anywhere will arrive to https://www.bbb.com

My old host is not exist any more and I don't want to renew SSL certificate for *.aaa.com domain.
I tried to change A record of @.aaa.com to point to bbb.com IP and
CNAME of www.aaa.com to point to www.bbb.com
In additional I added foloowing to .htaccess file:

*RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?aaa.com$

RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.bbb.com/ [R=301,L]*

In both cases I got certificate error and in browser address bar I see https://www.aaa.com

What is a best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do the redirect in DNS. DNS only controls which server gets the request. So whether you use an A record or CNAME record, the result is the same. The browser will still try to contact your webserver looking for `www.aaa.com`.

You are on the right track with the `.htaccess` file. But you will need to have a valid certificate for `www.aaa.com` in order for it to work without certificate errors. You could just [get a free Let's Encrypt certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) though. You do not have to pay for it.